# Google Library issues

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, libraries

I have been learning to program for a couple of months on my own now, and I have been trying to add Google Places onto my app that I am creating.

I am getting an error with GoogleHeaders and there is another error that is seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

I had to cut and paste the two sections of my libraries in a screenshot in order for everyone to be able to see it. I added these libraries after installing the Google plugin that is supposed to be easy to download the necessary libraries, but it cleared up some errors but these are the last errors I am dealing with.

Comment: What's the specific error? Do you have import statements?

Comment: the import cannot be resolved to a type. Thats what all of my errors are. I know they are correct because I have seen these codes being used all the time. I do know that google has made a v3 of maps and I am currently on 2, but I would like to stay where I am at so I can learn. Any suggestions? Pretty much my question is this: do I have too many libraries, or wrong ones that are causing errors for Google Places API?

Comment: Did you actually include the jars in the build path, and the imports at the top?

Comment: Well last time I did something with build path, my whole project went haywire. Is it possible to get help with that? I haven't done much with messing with build paths. So, to answer your question, no.

Comment: You need to add the jars to the build path.

Comment: how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Right-click the jar in your project(put it in a folder called lib. You may need to make this folder). Then select build path->add to build path. It's done automatically and gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the jar in your project(put it in a folder called lib. You may need to make this folder). Then select build path->add to build path. It's done automatically and gracefully.

This adds an entry to the .classpath file. Eclipse will find this jar and use it for imports for compile-time and run-time information.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I did this with no luck. I didn't help me. Is it possible to have too many libraries (.jars) added?

Comment: should any of the jars be added to the dependencies folder?